# Remote host file operations over SSH2 in java

Tags: java, ssh, file-listing

I've got a simple task for now: connect to a remote server and get list of files and their info (in particular date of creation).

Tried JSch, but it's like writing unix app 20 years ago. Would like to switch to sshj so if it's possible, please provide some code on how to achieve at least file listing and their info (ideally, I would like to get an array of File objects).

So how can I achieve the goal?

Thanks in advance.

NOTE: AFAIU it's only possible by having **ls** on server side and parsing it, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They have examples bundled with their source distribution. Did you look a them? I found this in 2 minutes: [sshj: how to execute remote command example](https://github.com/shikhar/sshj/blob/master/src/main/java/examples/Exec.java)

**Edit:**

Ok, you could execute for instance (basing on the example I linked):

```
final Command cmd = session.exec("ls -l /some/interesting/dir");
String lsOutput = cmd.getOutputAsString();

// parse lsOutput and extract required information
...
```

There is no simplier way if you want to do it over `ssh`, because it has no notion of files etc. It is just a remote shell. Maybe `sftp` could provide some better interface here, but I am no expert with `sftp`.

Comment: I'm not an advanced ssh/sftp user, so it looks like I lack understanding.

Comment: What information do you need? And actually, what do you want to achieve with this program?

Comment: I recommend the SFTP suggestion. sshj appears to support it.

Comment: @pajton, task is in the question body, it looks like your suggestion is the only one available. Strange that sftp has no info about date.

Comment: Right. I was rather thinking way in Java and why over ssh, but I guess you just have these constraints.

Comment: @pajton, actually, all this will result in a groovy script. :D

Comment: Maybe you know something like LsEntry in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484816/remote-host-file-operations-over-ssh2-in-java/5485262#5485262 so that I won't have to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Unfortunately no. If you are creating a script, I would use `bash` for this kind of scripting:-) (that's why I asked)

Comment: Me too, but I have certain specific conditions. That's why I provided the exact "end user" task. :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code for sftp (JSCH)

`ChannelSftp sftp = (ChannelSftp)session.openChannel("sftp");

    sftp.connect();

    sftp.cd(DIRECTORY);

    Vector v = null;

    v = sftp.ls("*.txt");  //txt files only`

Use with keyfile:

    `JSch jsch = new JSch();

    jsch.setKnownHosts(myKonfig.getKnownHostsFile());

    String privKeyFile = myKonfig.getPrivateKeyFile();

    jsch.addIdentity(privKeyFile);`

Comment: Is it possible to do some stuff without UserInfo, raw pass/username (I mean to get session)?

Comment: You can use a keyfile:

 JSch jsch = new JSch();

 jsch.setKnownHosts(myKonfig.getKnownHostsFile());

 String privKeyFile = myKonfig.getPrivateKeyFile();

 jsch.addIdentity(privKeyFile);

Comment: Actually, I did it with  session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no"); :)

Comment: Your answer is good, but unfortunately JSch is not my choice. It'll get me lots of headaches just because it lucks code doc. Thank you, though.

Answer (score 1):

> Oops, just saw that it doesn't return the creation time, just the modification time.

If you're just looking to get file information from the remote system, I would recommend using the SFTPClient class that's provided within sshj.

use the:

```
SFTPClient.ls(directory)
```

command to find all the remote files, then use the:

```
SFTPClient.stat(file)
```

to get all the information from the remote files including the date of modification.

Comment: It looks like the creation time is available on NTFS, on most unix/linux systems you don't get this information